# Permission denied when creating text file in asp

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, permission-denied, filesystemobject

I have the following code:

```
<%
dim deviceid
dim fso
dim outFile

deviceid=Request.QueryString("deviceid")

If deviceid<>"" Then
    Response.Write("Hello " & deviceid & "!<br>")

    Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\respTank.txt")
    outFile.WriteLine("Hello World!")
    outFile.close

    set outFile = nothing
    set fso = nothing

End If
%>
```

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'
Permission denied
```

I gave all permissions to IIS_IUSRS but it didn't help. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Is the web application running as the Application Pool Identity? If not adding `IIS_IUSRS` will not help.

Comment: the DefaultAppPool has the Application Pool Identity selected

Comment: Is the `DefaultAppPool` the Application Pool the web application is using?

Comment: Default Web Site has `DefaultAppPool` as Application Pool and `\inetpub\wwwroot` as Physical Path, where my asp file is located

Comment: Bit strange why you are trying to create a local file inside a User Profile directory, you might find there are extra security such as UAC (User Account Control) that is blocking the creation, other then that I can't help you sorry.

Comment: Also check you are setting the minimum permissions at the highest level (`list folder` in `C:\Users`) then inheriting down to `Desktop` and setting at least `modify` at this level.

Comment: where should create the file then? I tried also in the wwwroot directory but I get the same problem. If I use the method `Getfile` instead of the method `CreateTextFile` I get the message that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Sounds to me like the web application is using a different user context check the Authentication section in IIS. Regardless of the Application Pool you can still set your own `Anonymous Account` on the web application.

Comment: Thank you very much Lankymart! Indeed I had to change the user context of the web application to a user with enough rights. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` is not the user context being used by the Web Application.

Depending on the IIS Version, you want to check (using the Manager)

> **IIS 4-6**
>
> Web Site / Application Properties -> `Document Security`
>
> **IIS 7+**
>
> Web Site / Application -> `Authentication`

and check the `Anonymous Account` which can be set differently to the `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

Based on this value apply the permissions (at least `Modify`) to the folder `C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\` and you are good to go.

Answer (score -2):

I just had the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946852/fs-deletefilevar-not-deleting-file) happening on a delete file, have you tried removing the parenthesis?

```
Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\respTank.txt")
```

to

```
Set outFile = fso.CreateTextFile "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\respTank.txt"
```